# WPMU on MySQL limited to 1GB of space?

Tags: multisite, database

My MySQL databases are limited to 1024MB per 1 database but WPMU websites need to exceed that... Is there any way to make WPMU go and use `database_2` when `database_1` is already close to 1024MB?

I can have:

- `database_1` 1024MB
- `database_2` 1024MB
- `database_3` 1024MB
- `database_4` 1024MB
- etc.

I can't have:

- `database_1` 8192MB or more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no code I know of to automatically partition databases like that based on their size, but if you want to use something to manually split your system across multiple databases, then HyperDB is one way to do that.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hyperdb/